# How to automatically add a fixed amount to the invoice

Tags: python-2.7, odoo

I'm starting with OpenERP and I do not know how to automatically add a fixed amount to the invoice (eg stamp duty).

Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Hello, You can create a tax from Accounting -> Configuration -> Taxes -> Taxes with tax type "fixed" and putting desired amount and then add this tax into products default taxes(customer/supplier) from Product -> Accounting(Tab) -> Customer Taxes/ Supplier Taxes. So whenever you will select that product on invoice that amount will be automatically added as tax amount.

Comment: Or you can set default sale tax/purchase tax from Settings -> Configuration -> Accounting -> eInvoicing & Payments. Or at the time of installation of any accounting module it will ask for "Set your accounting option", you can provide tax rate over there. :)

Comment: Thanks Pooja, I have just created a module which add a field in the company called "default tax" then I add this tax to the total_amount of the invoice